# Are there simple memory-efficient ways to do multi-instance learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bagging

At the moment, I'm simply using mean of the features in all the instances in a bag to represent a given bag.  I've also tried using min/max, gmean and hmean, but didn't get any better results.

Are there other multi-instance learning approaches that may work well and don't have significantly larger memory or processing requirements?

Comment: could you quantify the buzzword "deep learning?" Are you using a convolutional neural net? Check out Caffe: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/   , which will work especially well if you have a decent GPU.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I think my references to deep learning distracted from my core question, so I've removed those references and  I've updated the question accordingly.